# Adding Migration is not adding table creation script in the Up method

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to add a new table to my database for which I wrote the below class in the entities.

```
namespace EconomyEnergy.Data.Entities
{
    public class AccountEmailMapping
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

        public int AccountId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("AccountId")]
        public Account AccountObj { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then I added migration but the up method doesn't contain any table creation script.

```
namespace EconomyEnergy.Data
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AddingAccountEmailMapping : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to code first, Can somebody please explain where I am making the mistake.
I tried to add a table a few days back and I was able to do it successfully.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: MAke sure in your DbCOntext you added DbSet<AccountEmailMapping>.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Exactly that the issue was, I added DbSet<AccountEmailMapping> and it is creating the script now. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I will write how I make my migrations. Which would show you the flow of execution.

In my "DB Context" I add the new data (a whole table or just a new coloumn) to the ModelBuilder like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Language>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("language", "common");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                .HasColumnName("id")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.Code)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("code");

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("name")
                .HasColumnType("varchar");
        });
```

Then you write in your console (Packet manager console would also work):

```
Add-Migration <insert migration name here>
```

[Add-Migration documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#add-migration)

This will create the migration files for you automatically.

Then just type in the PM console.

```
Update-Database
```

which would result in the migrations being made on the Database.